# given column of month and its corresponding values, How to find max value in each year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have used the code as below-

```
df['issue_date'].value_counts(ascending= False)

and I am getting output as attached -

Dec-11   -- 2260

Nov-11  --  2223

Oct-11  --  2114

Sep-11  --  2063

...

Dec-10  --   1267

Oct-10  --  1132

Nov-10  --  1121
```

...

I want to filter out max value for each year 2011, 2010 which is 2260 and 1267 respectively
Can you please advise.

Comment: you probably did not need to do a `value count`, a groupby and max probably could have done it for you.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of your dataframe please

Answer (score 0):

df['issue_date'].max(axis = 1, skipna = True)